# Notice: Undefined variable: cur_order in

Tags: php

I am getting an error : `Notice: Undefined variable: cur_order in` ,can anyone guide me where i am went wrong,below is my code:

```
<?php

class Products {

    var $name;
    var $description;
    var $productId;

    function Products($id = 0, $infoArr = array()) {
        if ($id > 0 && count($infoArr)) {
            $this->name = $infoArr['name'];
            $this->description = $infoArr['description'];
            $this->productId = $id;
        }
    }



    /**
     * @static
     */
    function loadAllProducts() {
        $arr = getProducts();
        $prods = array();
        foreach ($arr as $id=>$info) {
            $prods[$id] = new Products($id,$info);
        }

        return $prods;
    }

/**
 * function loadOrderDetails
 * 
 * This function should be giving us all the information about the order:
 * The customer's name and address, the products that were ordered (deescriptions too) and the order totals.
 * See products that php to see what is expected to be shown
 *
 * @param Integer   $order_id   the unique identifier for the order
 * @return Array    $cur_order  the details of the order
 * 
 */
    function loadOrderDetails($order_id) {
        $orders    = getOrderInfo();
        $products  = getProducts();
        $customer  = getCustomerInfo();
        $address   = getAddresses();


        return $cur_order;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Declare $cur_order variable in begging of function  loadOrderDetails()

Answer (score 3):

`$cur_order` does not exist in your code. How can you return it?

```
function loadOrderDetails($order_id) {
    $orders    = getOrderInfo();
    $products  = getProducts();
    $customer  = getCustomerInfo();
    $address   = getAddresses();


    return $cur_order; // <-- this variable does not exist
}
```

You can only return one of the four variables you have used in that method or any of the member variables of that class (although that wouldn't be relevant in this case).

Another observation, you pass `$order_id` as a parameter but never use it. Do you really need to have it be a parameter then?

Answer (score 0):

In your function "loadOrderDetails" you are returning variable $cur_order.  It doesn't look like you've defined this variable yet.

If you were to return $address it would probably work.  Or within the function define $cur_order = "test"

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the $cur_order variable inside the loadOrderDetails function but you have not declared it in the function.

Just use $cur_order = true;

If you need to load the variable from outside the function use global $cur_order;